# When installing Tableau Server getting error

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-services, tableau-api

When I am installing Tableau server I am seeing this server. I am the administrator of the system but still I was seeing the message.Please help me in this regard

[image: Below is the error I am seeing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often safer to use the default NTAuthority\NetworkService account if you're installing Tableau Server for the first time, since this is (almost always) guaranteed to work and can always be changed later.

If you do want to proceed with using SriHarsha-PC\SriHarsha as the Run As account, then take a look at the following link from the Tableau Software Knowledge Base which lists all of the permissions that your chosen account will need in order to run Tableau Server correctly.

[Tableau Server Run As account permissions](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#runas.htm)

If that does not provide sufficient information, then [create a support request](http://www.tableausoftware.com/support/request) and Tableau Technical Support will try and help resolve the issue.

Comment: Agreed. This solved a similar problem with an error message during installation along the lines of:

"the tableau server account failed to obtain the required permissions [...]"

...experienced during running the installer for doing an upgrade, from 9.2 to 10.0 in our case. We were using a domain account for the run-as. Changed it to "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" for the duration of the install, which then worked fine, and changed it back afterwards.

(NB the answer above has the account slightly incorrect; note the required space in "NT AUTHORITY").